# rails - caches_action expire_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, sweeper

I want to expire a cached action and wondered how to generate the correct reference.

```
#controller
caches_action :index, :layout => false
#generates this fragment which works fine
views/0.0.0.0:3000/article/someid/posts

#sweeper
...
expire_action article_posts_path(:article_id => post.article)
# results in this
Expired fragment: views//en/article/someid/posts (0.0ms)
```

So this is almost ok, except the host is missing. What do I do that supplies this to the expire_action method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `article_posts_url(:article_id => post.article)`

`resource_name_url` routes generate url with the host set.

Comment: aaaaaaah,,, so that's the difference between those two... Thanks :)